# Performance hibernate @Subselect vs database view

Tags: database, spring-boot, performance, hibernate, view

I have a Java 8  Spring Boot 2.3.3 based application (use hibernate 5.4.20), I have a Postgresql under.
I would like to finally understand if it is better (for perfomance) to use or not a database view and or @Subselect.

Just a rapid overview: I have an entity "Book" and 3 entity "BookRank" (users give 1 to 10 *stars* to the books) , "BookComment" (user comments to the book) , "BookLike" (users put *like* to the books) each having the Book relation (ManyToOne), so in my query result I want to order the books in this way:

```
order by avg(book_rank) desc, sum(book_rank) desc, count(book_comment) desc, count(book_like) desc
```

Ofcourse there are a lot of book, a lot of ranks, comments and likes... :)

*I found 4 ways to do the same thing starting from a complicated query with 3 sub select inside (it was for me the best solution, but if someone have a better way to do it please tell me).*

```
select *
from(
    select bbb.id as book_id, min(bbb.b_rank_average) as b_rank_average, min(bbb.b_rank_sum) as b_rank_sum, min(bbb.b_comment_count) as b_comment_count, count(b_l.id) as b_like_count
    from(
        select rr.id, min(bb.b_rank_average) as b_rank_average, min(bb.b_rank_sum) as b_rank_sum, count(b_c.id) as b_comment_count
        from(           
            select b.id,  avg(b_r.rank) as b_rank_average, sum(b_r.rank) as b_rank_sum
            from book as b
            left join book_rank as b_r on (b.id = b_r.book_id and b_r.deleted = false)
            group by b.id) as bb
            
        left join book_comment as b_c on (bb.id = b_c.book_id and b_c.deleted = false)
        group by bb.id) as bbb
                
    left join book_like as b_l on (bbb.id = b_l.book_id and b_l.deleted = false)
    group by bbb.id
    ) as bbbb
    
left join book on bbbb.book_id = book.id
where book.deleted = false
order by b_rank_average desc nulls last, b_rank_sum desc nulls last, b_comment_count desc, b_like_count desc, book_id desc;
```

*I would like to know which one is the best performat...*

**1) pure native query in the repository - no view - no immutable entity**

In my repository I just have a method with the native query written above

**2) with a database view and native query in the repository**

Creating a database view with the center part of the query:

```
create or replace view book_ranking as

    select bbb.id as book_id, min(bbb.b_rank_average) as b_rank_average, min(bbb.b_rank_sum) as b_rank_sum, min(bbb.b_comment_count) as b_comment_count, count(b_l.id) as b_like_count
    from(
        select rr.id, min(bb.b_rank_average) as b_rank_average, min(bb.b_rank_sum) as b_rank_sum, count(b_c.id) as b_comment_count
        from(           
            select b.id,  avg(b_r.rank) as b_rank_average, sum(b_r.rank) as b_rank_sum
            from book as b
            left join book_rank as b_r on (b.id = b_r.book_id and b_r.deleted = false)
            group by b.id) as bb
            
        left join book_comment as b_c on (bb.id = b_c.book_id and b_c.deleted = false)
        group by bb.id) as bbb
                
    left join book_like as b_l on (bbb.id = b_l.book_id and b_l.deleted = false)
    group by bbb.id
```

and modifying the native query in the repository method just to use the view:

```
select * 
from book_ranking as the_view
left join book on the_view.book_id = book.id 
where book.deleted = false
order by b_rank_average desc nulls last, b_rank_sum desc nulls last, b_comment_count desc, b_like_count desc, book_id desc;
```

**3) with a database view and an immutable entity that select the view and jpql query in repository**

Using an entity (immutable) to encapsulate the view above

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select * from book_ranking")
public class BookRanking implements Serializable {
    ....
}
```

and modifying the repository query (not native) that join the Book entity and the new BookRanking immutable entity (that is the view)

```
@Query("select b from BookRanking as b_r 
        join Book b on b_r.bookId = b.id 
        where b.deleted = false
        order by b_r.b_rank_average desc nulls last, b_r.b_rank_sum desc nulls last, b_r.b_comment_count desc, b_r.b_like_count desc, b_r.bookId desc)
```

**4) No view but immutable entity with the query in the @subselect and jpql query in repository**

No view on the database but the immutable entity BookRanking has the query in the @Subselect annotation with the 'view query' and the @Synchronize annotation like this:

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select bbb.id as book_id, min(bbb.b_rank_average) as b_rank_average, min(bbb.b_rank_sum) as b_rank_sum, min(bbb.b_comment_count) as b_comment_count, count(b_l.id) as b_like_count
    from(
        select rr.id, min(bb.b_rank_average) as b_rank_average, min(bb.b_rank_sum) as b_rank_sum, count(b_c.id) as b_comment_count
        from(           
            select b.id,  avg(b_r.rank) as b_rank_average, sum(b_r.rank) as b_rank_sum
            from book as b
            left join book_rank as b_r on (b.id = b_r.book_id and b_r.deleted = false)
            group by b.id) as bb
            
        left join book_comment as b_c on (bb.id = b_c.book_id and b_c.deleted = false)
        group by bb.id) as bbb
                
    left join book_like as b_l on (bbb.id = b_l.book_id and b_l.deleted = false)
    group by bbb.id )

@Synchronize({ "book", "book_rank", "book_comment", "book_like" })

public class BookRanking implements Serializable {
    ....
}
```

and using the same repository query (not native) that join the Book entity and the new BookRanking immutable entity (that is like the view)  of point 3

Comment: Which strategy did you use and how are the results so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a database view is just a relation that is expanded into a query plan, usually during parse time, so there should be no notable difference when using a view vs. writing out the whole query directly. Using a view allows you to reuse the query more easily but when you want to change something, you will have to change the view and maybe also all applications that use the view, so the reusability aspect can bite you back.

I usually don't recommend views because I have seen people put in a lot of unnecessary joins into the views for the sole purpose of "making it easier" for others. The problem with joins that aren't used is, that databases usually can't eliminate them. TLDR, I recommend writing out the queries directly in the code because you can omit joins that you don't need and thus get better performance.

You could use the following simpler query:

```
select 
    b.id, 
    avg(b_r.rank) as b_rank_average, 
    sum(b_r.rank) as b_rank_sum,
    (select count(*) from book_comment as b_c where b.id = b_c.book_id and b_c.deleted = false) as b_comment_count
    (select count(*) from book_like as b_l where b.id = b_l.book_id and b_l.deleted = false) as b_like_count
from book as b
left join book_rank as b_r      on (b.id = b_r.book_id and b_r.deleted = false)
where b.deleted = false
group by b.id
order by b_rank_average desc nulls last, b_rank_sum desc nulls last, b_comment_count desc, b_like_count desc, b.id desc
```

which could also be modeled with a JPQL/HQL query. It would look very similar:

```
select 
    b.id, 
    avg(r.rank) as b_rank_average, 
    sum(r.rank) as b_rank_sum,
    (select count(*) from b.comments c where c.deleted = false) as b_comment_count
    (select count(*) from b.booksLike l where l.deleted = false) as b_like_count
from book as b
left join b.ranks as r on r.deleted = false
where b.deleted = false
group by b.id
order by b_rank_average desc nulls last, b_rank_sum desc nulls last, b_comment_count desc, b_like_count desc, b.id desc
```